# Change default index.html page of a subdomain in directadmin

Tags: apache, subdomain, files

When I create a new subdomain in direct admin panel it gets a default placeholder page saying something between the lines "welcome, the page is under construction" or whatever.

I've looked online how to change it but only found info about how to change the default page of a main domain if I were to create one, and it directs me to file `home/resellername/domains/default/index.html` which indeed works. But the thing is the subdomains appearantly have a different placeholder page and they don't have similar file structure (I cannot find any `default` folder which would hold any templates for placeholder pages).

Can anyone tell me how do I change the default template `index.html` file for subdomains in direct admin?